# run .sql file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the below sql I need to run to create a database and assign a user to it ect...

Would I better off just creating all of this using PHP, or could I actually run this .sql file to create it all?

```
CREATE DATABASE 'ppa'

CREATE USER 'ppa_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'fSMthSGKVpDtcxDv';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON 'ppa'.* TO 'ppa_user'@'localhost';

CREATE TABLE 'ppa'.'users' (
    'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    'email' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    'password' CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    'perms' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    'salt' CHAR(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE 'ppa'.'login_attepts' (
    'user_id' INT(11) NOT NULL,
    'time' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO 'ppa'.'users' VALUES(1, 'admin', 'af453d19feb2520c8c0d30fb39ebd211', 'admin', '8269ebbf4c9cf901170ad58238deabb1');
```

The passwords are only randomly generated ones so it doesn't matter at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function to execute the .sql file and run all the queries written in the .sql file

```
<?php
//Import (executes) the SQL passed as parameter making some proper adaptations.
        function dbImportSQL($sql, $needle = '')
        {
            $sql = str_replace('/*TABLE_PREFIX*/', DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $sql);
            $sentences = explode( $needle . ';', $sql);
            // PREPARE THE QUERIES
            $var_l = count($sentences);
            $s_temp = '';
            for($var_k=0;$var_k<$var_l;$var_k++) {
                $s = $s_temp.$sentences[$var_k];
                if(!empty($s) && trim($s)!='') {
                    $s .= $needle;
                    $simple_comma = substr_count($s, "'");
                    $scaped_simple_comma = substr_count($s, "\'");
                    if(($simple_comma-$scaped_simple_comma)%2==0) {
                        $sentences[$var_k] = $s;
                        $s_temp = '';
                        //echo "[OK] ".$s." <br />";
                    } else {
                        unset($sentences[$var_k]);
                        $s_temp = $s.";";
                        //echo "[FAIL] ".$s." <br />";
                    }
                } else {
                    unset($sentences[$var_k]);
                }
            }

            foreach($sentences as $s) {
                $s = trim($s);
                if( !empty($s) ) {
                    $s = trim($s);// . $needle;
                    if( $this->db->query($s) ) {
                        $this->debug($s);
                    } else {
                        $this->debug($s . ' | ' . $this->db->error . ' (' . $this->db->errno . ')', false);
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->db_errno = $this->db->errno;

            if ($this->db_errno != 0) return false;
            return true;
        }
?>
```

Note: Please replace `$this->db`  with your database object

Then after you have created the function now call it with the below code

```
$path = 'struct.sql';// define the path for the .sql file 
        $sql = file_get_contents($path);
        dbImportSQL($sql);//this will read all the queries from the sql file and execute them
```

Below is the sample sql(struct.sql) file you can make changes if needed in the function according to your exact needs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_cpviewer_plan_headers (
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cp` text NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uploaded` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_cpviewer_plan_levels (
  `sid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CP` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `label` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_item ADD cp_number VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL AFTER dt_expiration ,
ADD cp_level INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AFTER cp_number;
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow thanks, also, do I need to replace /*TABLE_PREFIX*/ with anything?

Comment: /*TABLE_PREFIX*/ is just if you are using any kind of prefix in the table names normally used in joomla and wordpress by default if you don't want that prefix remove it from the sql file and remove the below line from the function also

$sql = str_replace('/*TABLE_PREFIX*/', DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $sql);

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file into a string and use a standard method for insertion.

Tools like phpMyAdmin have .sql import functionality.